# flask celery downloading a file, but the file doesn't refresh

Tags: flask, celery

I'm running a task in the background that is filling a database.
Then I have an HTML button that points to the following route (I didn't know what to put in the mimetype, so I let it to be text/csv, although I want to download the db):

```html
@app.route('/downloadDatabaseNow/')
def download_db():
    return send_file('myPath/myData.db',
                     mimetype='text/csv',
                     attachment_filename='myPath/myData.db',
                     as_attachment=True)
```

The problem is that the database I want to download is not refreshed. But the database is actually being filled in the background (I can see that because the file itself is getting bigger). So, when I want to download the database after 10min for example, the file size that is displayed in the pop up window when clicking on the button, is always the same (12 ko). The HTML button is :

```html
 <form action="/downloadDatabaseNow/">
        <input type="submit" value="Download database" />
    </form>
```

I also have to say that when I change the file to be downloaded (for example an image) then the file displayed in the pop up window is the previous file (the database). I need to change the name of the route, so that it refreshed properly, in order to download the image. The thing is that the image is a static file, whereas my database is being filled by a celery task in the background. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I think I've found a partial solution. I need to delete my recent history of websites (so the cache of firefox) in order to make it work. Is there any other method ? I don't want the user to do it him/her self. Thanks

Comment: add timestamp to avoid cache maybe a solution. Or you can add HTTP header `Cache-control: no-cache` to tell browser "Don't cache"